# HTTP request from PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

In my phantomJS script, I want to make a few HTTP requests to set up some variables in Phantom before using it to scrape HTML content.

What is the correct way to do HTTP requests from PhantomJS?
Should I use the PageObject and handle it as if it was a webpage?
Or is there some XHR functionality I can use for this?
I want to fetch some Json data first.

Comment: You could also consider passing parameters into the Phantom script as command line arguments.

Answer (score 3):

You've got a few different options to consider. The easiest way to accomplish this would be to use the WebPage module, open the URL of the page with the data you want to load, and then go about scraping other pages with other webpage objects.

```
var webpage = require('webpage');
var page = webpage.create()
page.open('<some url>', function(status) {
  var option1 = page.evaluate(function() { ... });
  var option2 = page.evaluate(function() { ... });

  another = webpage.create();
  another.open('<another url>', function(status) {
    another.evaluate(function(opt1, opt2) {

      // you have access to opt1 and opt2 here

    }, option1, option2);
  });
  page.close();
});
```

Then you have access to the option1 and option2 variables in the 'another' page.

The other option is to use command line arguments as Joe mentioned above. You could even write your PhantomJS code that accept command line arguments for the variables, write a Node.js/Python/Ruby script that makes a web request, parses it, and spawns the PhantomJS processes with the proper command line arguments.

Both would work, but if you want to keep your code in one file I would go the first route.

Comment: I am spawning my script from a webserver and passing in arguments via command line, however I need to send frequent updates to the control server while my script is running. Using a WebPage object is super heavyweight, even more so since I am using Slimer as opposed to Phantom (a requirement for this task). Since I can't use the node http module, is there perhaps a standalone http module that I could use. Or curl maybe?

Comment: I don't see anything in the [SlimerJS docs](http://docs.slimerjs.org/current/) that could be used to spawn commands and buffer output (which you would need to run a Linux command like curl). I think using a webpage object to accomplish this may be your only option here.

Comment: I didn't find anything either, so I used a webpage object. It is odd because in the Phantom docs there is even a section called Inter Process Communcation which suggests using outgoing http requests to an external server: http://phantomjs.org/inter-process-communication.html Unfortunately they dont give any concrete examples. Thanks for looking though. Maybe I will put in a feature request.

Comment: Looking through their examples it looks like the only way to send http requests is using page.open - Here's an example of a post request: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/post.js - You can pass the request type as the second paramater

Comment: This was by far the easiest way I found. I also tried using an XMLHttpRequest within the page, but that got really fiddly. Thanks!